# How do i add ctc beam search decoder in crnn model (pytorch)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, ocr, speech-recognition, pytorch

I am following the CRNN implementation of https://github.com/meijieru/crnn.pytorch, but seems like it is not using beam search for decoding the words. Can someone tell me how to add beam search decoding in the same model? At the same time in Tensorflow, there is an inbuilt `tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder`.

Comment: See https://github.com/ottokart/beam_search for a ref beam search implementation

Answer (score -3, accepted):

i know its not a great idea, but i did it using tensorflow inside pytorch.

```
if(beam):
        decodes, _ = tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder(inputs=preds_.cpu().detach().numpy(), 
                     sequence_length=25*np.ones(1), merge_repeated=False)
        with tf.Session(config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count = {'GPU': 0})) as sess:
            t_ = sess.run(decodes)[0].values
            char_list = []
            for i in range(len(sess.run(decodes)[0].values)):
                    if t_[i] != 0 and (not (i > 0 and t_[i - 1] == t_[i])):
                        char_list.append(alphabet[t_[i] - 1])
            sim_pred = ''.join(char_list)
else:        
        raw_pred = converter.decode(preds.data, preds_size.data, raw=True)
        sim_pred = converter.decode(preds.data, preds_size.data, raw=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply add your own beam search decoder to the model?
Shouldn't be too difficult.

Search through the CRNN code to find the [line where decoding happens at the moment](https://github.com/meijieru/crnn.pytorch/blob/master/crnn_main.py#L158):

```
sim_preds = converter.decode(preds.data, preds_size.data, raw=False)
```

Ok, seems like preds.data holds the output tensor of the neural network. 
Instead of calling converter.decode(...), pass this tensor to a beam search decoder.
You can take my [CTC beam search implementation](https://github.com/githubharald/CTCDecoder/blob/master/src/BeamSearch.py).

Call BeamSearch.ctcBeamSearch(...), pass a single batch element with softmax already applied (mat), pass a string holding all characters (in the order the neural network outputs them), and pass None for the language model (you can later add it if you like). 
The matrix mat must be of shape Tx(C+1), where T is the number of time-steps and C+1 is the number of characters plus the blank.
The blank is assumed to be the LAST entry, so take care of it.

Here is a minimalistic example:

```
mat = np.array([[0.4, 0, 0.6], [0.4, 0, 0.6]]) # TxC with T=2, C=3
classes = 'ab' # all chars in the order they appear in mat (without blank)
res = BeamSearch.ctcBeamSearch(mat, classes, None) # decode it
```

[Here is another example](https://github.com/githubharald/CTCDecoder/blob/master/src/main.py#L92) for a more realistic use case to decode the output of a real text recognition system.